# The conjugate function of infimal convolution

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

There is a similar discussion:
[Infimal convolution conjugate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118526/infimal-convolution-conjugate)

I just want to ask how to prove that for convex $f_i$ $\forall i$ if

$$
g(x) = \inf\{f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)|x_1+x_2=x\}
$$

then $g^{*}(y) = f_1^{*}(y)+f_2^{*}(y)$ ?

---

We know the definition for the conjugate function is $$g^*(y) = \sup_x \{\langle x,y \rangle - g(x)\}
$$

We have the following:
$$g^*(y) = \sup_x \{\langle x,y \rangle - (\inf\{f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)|x_1+x_2=x)\}
$$

Then how to deal with this complicated term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{align}g^*(y) &= \sup_{x,x_1,x_2} \{ x^Ty - f_1(x_1) - f_2(x_2) | x_1+x_2 = x \} \\
&= \sup_{x_1,x_2} \{ (x_1+x_2)^Ty - f_1(x_1) - f_2(x_2)\} \\
&= \sup_{x_1,x_2} \{ x_1^Ty - f_1(x_1) + x_2^Ty - f_2(x_2)\} \\
&= \sup_{x_1} \{ x_1^Ty - f_1(x_1) \} + \sup_{x_2} \{ x_2^Ty - f_2(x_2)\}
\end{align}$$

Comment: In the first line, how could you remove the "$\inf$"?   ($g(x) = \inf $...)

Comment: I used that $\inf(f(x)) = -\sup(-f(x))$.

Comment: So from this proof, the identity holds for any proper functions (can be highly discontinuous) defined on any normed vector space that can be infinite dimensional . Right ?